# error while executing select query while using if conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT IF(a+b+c = 180,"triangle","Not A Triangle") from TRIANGLES;
```

> SELECT IF(a+b+c = 180,"triangle","Not A Triangle") from TRIANGLES 
>   *  ERROR at line 1:  **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**

Comment: As @GordonLinoff say you should use a case statement and use single quote with your string not double quotes , you cal also try to use [decode](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php), Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF()` -- although supported in some databases -- is not the right construct.  The right construct is `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN a+b+c = 180 THEN 'triangle' ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
        END) 
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Also note that strings are delimited by single quotes, not double quotes.